# pandas df - calculate percentage difference not change

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the percentage difference not change or just the difference between two values.

my df:

```
                           Radisson Collection      
6                                                                  
Total awareness             0.440553            
Very/Somewhat familiar      0.462577           
Consideration               0.494652             
Ever used                   0.484620
```

Expected output:

```
                            Radisson Collection      
6                                                                  
Total awareness             none            
Very/Somewhat familiar      4.87726%           
Consideration               6.70163%            
Ever used                   2.04886%
```

The calculation would be:

```
Difference of 0.440553 and 0.462577 = |0.440553 - 0.462577|/((0.440553 + 0.462577)/2) = 0.022024/0.451565 = 0.048772601950993 = 4.8772601950993%
```

Comment: df.series.diff() ?

Comment: just gives me the diff between two values, does not calculate the difference in percentages

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with closing, not tested before. And thank you for formula.

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with absolute values by [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) with [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) `mean`:

```
s = df['Radisson Collection'].rolling(2).mean()
df['new'] = df['Radisson Collection'].diff().abs().div(s) * 100
print (df)
                        Radisson Collection       new
Total awareness                    0.440553       NaN
Very/Somewhat familiar             0.462577  4.877260
Consideration                      0.494652  6.701636
Ever used                          0.484620  2.048869
```

If need percentages:

```
df['new'] = (df['Radisson Collection'].diff().abs().div(s) * 100)
                    .iloc[1:].round(5).astype(str) + '%'
```